# Consultar base de datos o archivo json

Tags: mysql, json

Buenas.

Voy a redactar lo mas específico posible.

Quiero realizar un sistema de notificaciones el cual informara a los usuarios que se les ha respondido una solicitud. Utilizo PHP sin framework y Mysql.

Puedo crear una tabla para guardar y actualizar la cantidad actual de solicitudes de cada usuario, que cada vez que se responda una solicitud el numero asociado a la cantidad de soliciudes de ese usuario aumente y al consultar la base de datos mediante ajax optener el número para ser comparado con un count de la tablas de solicitudes generadas por el usuario.

La otra opción es crear un archivo json obviamente no consultara la base de datos, la idea de este es que cuando sean respondías las solicitudes consulte y escriba el archivo json asociado a este usuario.

El  archivo tendría un array que contenga el nombre de usuario, cantidad actual de solicitudes, cantidad nueva etc.
Al usuario pulsar el icono de notificaciones el archivo se actualiza y la cantidad de solicitudes nueva será igual al actual y no le notificaria hasta que el proceso se repita.

En fin mi pregunta es que sería mas eficiente?

Nota: El sistema actualmente tiene mas de 300 usuarios simultaneos conectados, también se como hacer las dos opciones aunque estoy abierto a otras alternativas.

Nota2: Es un sistema que esta en una red cerrada por lo que no puedo depender de servicios externos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

¡Hola! No es buena práctica manipular archivos JSON directamente ni almacenar datos en ellos, cualquier error te podría hacer perder todos esos datos.

Si quieres que sea ultra dinámico (y sin gastar espacio en tu servidor) podrías pegarle una mirada a Firebase (https://firebase.google.com/), pero tiene su curva de aprendizaje. Firebase está destinado a este tipo de problemáticas.

Si necesitas algo más conocido, yo pondría en la misma tabla de solicitudes una columna booleana "visto", la cuál es por defecto False y pasa a True con Ajax cuando un usuario vé la solicitud. No haría una tabla específica para eso, me parece redundante y más dificil de escalar. Para mostrar la cantidad de notificaciones en el WHERE le pones que user_id sea el id del usuario y que visto sea False.

Espero haber entendido bien tu problema y que mi respuesta te sea útil,
¡Saludos!

Comment: Excelente. Muchas gracias. Lo del archivo json la idea es que sea 1 para cada usuario no 1 para todos.

Comment: Si, el problema es que pierdes un montón de mecanismos de garantizar la integridad y la manipulación de los datos que tienen las bases de datos, vas a tener problemas con caracteres especiales, si necesitas sobreescribir un dato por alguna razón, si necesitas unir esos datos a otros por alguna razón, si quieres permitir editar pero evitar inyecciones de código, también le va a costar entenderlo a futuros desarrolladores y pueden accidentalmente borrar datos, cuesta más respaldar o generar redundancia, te genera una fuente de datos más de la que estar preocupado, etc. ¡Saludos!

Comment: Excelente explicación. Gracias

Comment: ¡No hay problema! Si te fue útil por favor marcarla como respuesta correcta, te estaré muy agradecido. ¡Saludos y éxito!

Answer (score 1):

Si ya tienes trabajando la base de datos MySQL, úsala mejor para todas tus tareas, de hecho te comento que a partir de la versión 5.7 de MySQL puedes almacenar JSON como lo harías en un archivo tradicional; lo único que requieres es crear el campo que va a almacenar dicha info del modo siguiente:

```
CREATE TABLE solicitudes( 
   id INT,
   solicitud_respondida JSON NOT NULL,
   nombre_solicitud VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
   pk_solicitudes PRIMARY KEY(id)
);
```

Si te das cuenta seguimos con la misma estructura clásica para crear tablas con lenguaje SQL pero puedes agregar estructura JSON como lo notas espero te sirva.

Comment: Muchas gracias! voy a leer sobre esto, actualmente el sistema al responder una solicitud busca en la carpeta del usuario un archivo json y si este existe le suma 1 a la posición del arreglo que se encarga de guardar la cantidad de notificaciones, de no existir lo crea y realiza el mismo calculo.